# Query table with compound primary keys

Tags: sql, database, pandas, pyodbc

I'm using `pyodbc` to connect to a machine database, and query a number of tables in that database using

`pandas.read_sql(tbl,cnxn), where tbl = "SELECT * FROM TABLE", cnxn is pyodbc.connect('DSN=DATASOURCE;UID=USERID;PWD=PASSWORD').`

It works on most tables, but some tables return:

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM TABLE': ('42S02', '[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-00942: table or view does not exist (942) (SQLExecDirectW)')

These tables that return an error, when opened in MS Access, have multiple columns  with a key icon on the left when opened in design view (thus a **compound** primary key, made up from multiple columns).

Is this is the reason I'm having the error described above? How can I solve this?

**Edit**: as shown in this screenshot, there are multiple columns marked as making up the primary key in design view:

[image]

**Edit2**:Thanks for the feedbacks. After checking ODBC Data Source Administrator window, this data source is on 32-bit platform, and its driver is Microsoft ODBC for Oracle.

I don't think table's name is the issue, because other tables worked and they have the same naming convention (table name is in this format `NAME_OF_THE_TABLE`). Trying to avoid showing the table name because working on a company project.

I did research the concept of primary key and realized that there can only be one for a table, but as shown in the screenshot attached, there are a five fields shows a key icon on the left.

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with primary keys.

Comment: sorry, i'm editing this now

Comment: You **cannot** by definition have **mulitple** primary keys on a table - there's always only **at most ONE** primary key - but it can be made up from multiple columns (and then it's called a **compound primary key**)

Comment: Please show the names of tables that throw that error. I have a working theory. Also, are these Oracle linked tables in MS Access? Tag your database specifically.

Comment: Yes, I think it's using Oracle. I'm not sure if these Oracle linked to tables in MS Access, but I doubt it. Still my theory is there's something different about tables with multiple fields that have that key icons attached to them.

Comment: In MS Access navigation pane, do the tables have arrows to the left of their names? Please post the `pyodbc.connection()` call (of course redact any privileged, user credentials). We need to see your ODBC driver type.

Comment: Make the edit showing the connection string.

Comment: I can't answer that MS Access question for sure. I'll have to check with our database management team on how they construct this table. But I can access this table using MS Access, External Data >> New Data Source >> from other sources >> ODBC Database >> Machine Data Source >> select table. Not sure if this answers your question.

Comment: All you have to do to answer is look at the Navigation Pane (CTRL+L) and see if the listed tables have [arrows with globes](https://images.app.goo.gl/WWGSotanJ3TVWfNz9) to the left of their names. Nonetheless, you did answer my question as they are linked tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything, understand MS Access is a [unique](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33216/ms-access-or-mdb-or-access-database-engine-or-ms-jet-ace), GUI tool that maintains its own default database, JET/ACE Engine, but can connect to other databases as well including Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres, etc. via OLEDB/ODBC connections. Essentially, both MS Access and Python are doing the same thing: make an ODBC connection to Oracle (the actual backend database).

Because all [linked tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-linked-tables-1d9346d6-953d-4f85-a9ce-4caec2262797) connect fine in MS Access, try matching connections and queries in Python. Likely, the issue involves table names, schema connection, or user access.

1. **Table Name**: Your table contains misspellings or [reserved words](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm), or a mix of upper or lower cases as defined in their `CREATE TABLE` setup causing case sensitivity, so `Table` as defined with `CREATE TABLE "Table"` is not the same as `TABLE`. For this reason, use the exact name in the MS Access linked table and wrap with double quotes.

   ```
   pandas.read_sql('SELECT * FROM "Table"', cnxn)
   ```

   (Do note: double quotes in SQL is entirely different meaning than double quotes in Python and are not interchangeable with single quotes.)
2. **Connected Schema/User**: Incorrect schema. Because schemas in Oracle are more or less users, you may have multiple connections for your MS Access linked tables. Though they all point to same database server with same ODBC driver, the user differs each with different underlying tables. To resolve, match the Python ODBC connection with the MS Access ODBC connection:

   You can locate the MS Access connection string under: Table Design (from Navigation Pane) > Property Sheet (from Ribbon) > Description. Use this in the `pyodbc.connect(...)` call. Likely only the `uid` and `pwd` would differ if working across schemas.
3. **Unprivileged User**: The connected user does not have `select` [privilege](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTSQL/privileges.htm#TTSQL343) on that table.

Comment: I checked Description under Property Sheet and changed table name. Somehow it worked. That's awesome, thanks! It's so confusing because same method worked on other tables from the same data source!

Comment: Great! And shouldn't you now be sure of why it *somehow worked*? What were the names of tables that erred out in Python? Did they have case sensitivity, (i.e., `Table` vs `TABLE`)? Future readers who land on this page may need to know.

Comment: OK I'll describe the situation here. When I load a linked table into MS Access, when I select the table, the table name is `ABC.NAME_OF_THE_TABLE`, `ABC` is the name of our record keeping system. But when the table is loaded to MS Access, it's name is changed to `ABC_NAME_OF_THE_TABLE` under `All Access Objects` tab, the dot changed to underscore. For some tables, I would ignore `ABC` and only specify table name as `NAME_OF_THE_TABLE` and that worked for these tables. But for tables I have issues with, I have to specify `ABC.NAME_OF_THE_TABLE`. I have no theory on how this works!

Comment: `ABC` is likely the schema name and you connect at the database level above all schemas. So in Python query include full names [`schema.table`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm).